# Procedure to get number of days in month from timestamp stored in number type PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, unix-timestamp, date-arithmetic

I have a Unix timestamp value from Java which is stored as a numeric datatype . I must get the number of days in month from the timestamp.

I try to create a stored procedure like that but with no effect:

```
FUNCTION countDaysInMonth(millis NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  daysInMonth NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + millis / 86400000)))
  END
  INTO daysInMonth
  FROM dual;
  RETURN daysInMonth;
END countDaysInMonth;
```

Someone can help me with that? I'm totally beginner in PL/SQL

Comment: What do you mean by "no effect"? Do you receive a wrong number, an error or what? Your query seems correct. Make sure that the function receives a 13-digits number, and if it receives a 10-digits - change 86400000 to 86400.

Comment: What does the `millis` parameter actually contain, as in "what's the number which is passed in that parameter"? And what's your expected result?

Comment: Yes you're right . I made a mistake sending 10-digits number and not changing the divisor to 86400.  Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be like this:

```
FUNCTION countDaysInMonth(millis NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
     RETURN EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' +  millis/1000 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND));
END countDaysInMonth;
```